# Form builder and multilingual support

Tags: multilingual, formbuilder

I'm building a multilingual web app in which an admin can create forms (through a form builder) that users use to insert some info.

As the web app has to support multilanguage, I think the admin has to add translations for the field names, and for the select input fields.

I would to semplify the translation job for the admin. How could I do?